# libldap openldap setting option fails for simple SSL connection

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openldap

I am using openLdap (libldap) on Linux for building a simple  SSL connection client.

I get the following error:

```
ldap_set_option(pLdap, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
```

returns -1. Has anyone else seen this problem?

I am initializing ldap with

```
ldap_initialize (&pLdap,"ldaps://localhost:10636");
```

Please, do not redirect me to MSDN site for using `wldap32.lib` with

```
ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE, &VerifyCert);
```

and a callback function. That works, but only on windows.

Furthermore, I can't change the server configuration.

Comment: 2 Petesh. Seems set opt is successed now. But the last problem is that ldap_bind_s() returns -1.

Comment: I don't think there's enough code or error information to help. There's a man page on [`ldap_set_option`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_set_option). There's also a man page on [`ldap_error`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_error).

Comment: `ldap_bind_s` returns `-1` means that the server is not responding (please use `ldap_err2string` to determine the meaning of error codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the parameter in an enclosing value, not as the value itself.

```
int invalue = LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER;
err = ldap_set_option(0, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, &invalue);
```

Note that we can use `0` for the ldap handle because this option is for all connections.